# sgx_ecc256_create_key_pair fail

Tags: c++, visual-studio, elliptic-curve, sgx

I've written a very simple test to learn working with elliptic curve cryptography inside an enclave. But the key creation method fails with SGX_ERROR_UNEXPECTED.

Here is my enclave:

```
#include "Enc_t.h"

#include "sgx_trts.h"
#include "sgx_tcrypto.h"

int Test(sgx_status_t *error)
{
    sgx_ecc_state_handle_t handle;
    sgx_ec256_private_t sk;
    sgx_ec256_public_t pk;
    sgx_status_t status;

    status = sgx_ecc256_open_context(&handle);
    if (status)
    {
        *error = status;
        return 1;
    }

    status = sgx_ecc256_create_key_pair(&sk, &pk, &handle);
    if (status)
    {
        *error = status;
        return 2;
    }

    *error = SGX_SUCCESS;
    return 0;
}
```

and this is my host app:

```
#include "Enc_u.h"
#include "sgx_urts.h"
#include <cstdio>
#include <tchar.h>

#define ENC _T("../Debug/Enc.signed.dll")

int main()
{
    sgx_status_t error;
    sgx_enclave_id_t eid;
    sgx_launch_token_t token;
    int updated = 0;
    int step;
    error = sgx_create_enclave(ENC, SGX_DEBUG_FLAG, &token, &updated, &eid, nullptr);

    if (error)
        printf("Failed to create enclave\n");

    Test(eid, &step, &error);

    if (error)
        printf("Failed on step %d\n", step);

    return 0;
}
```

The result is error = 1 on step = 2.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong or what I might have configured incorrectly? I'm using Visual Studio Community 2015 and Intel C++ Compiler 17.0.

P.S: This is a replica of [my post on an Intel forum](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-software-guard-extensions-intel-sgx/topic/711087). If it's properly answered on each of these platforms, I'll post the answer to the other, also citing its author.

Comment: Can you share the edl statements

Comment: The EDL doesn't matter. The problem was due to passing a pointer to the EC context variable instead of itself. If you need it for another reason, let me know.

Comment: I need it use it as a tutorial. It would be really useful.
gmate.sunny@gmail.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the statement below instead of `status = sgx_ecc256_create_key_pair(&sk, &pk, &handle);`

- `status = sgx_ecc256_create_key_pair(&sk, &pk, handle);`